# How to match the values of a column of dataframe with the correct rows in other dataframes?

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have a number of csv files with dates (as daily) and temperature data. The files, however, comes in different dates (sometime overlaps, have missing dates, ….). What I want to do it to create a source file with the first column as the date (include all dates), and add columns of temperature data from the different csv files, corresponding to the date.

to make it simpler I'm considering I have only one file (df1).
So I defined the datetime (df2) as my source file, and tried to use pd.concate() to add the df1 into that. This works, but it removes the dates that are not available from the df1, while I want to keep all the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Datestart':['1/1/2010', '1/2/2010', '1/5/2010', '1/10/2010'],   'Temp':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2010', end='1/20/2010', freq='D')
df3 = pd.concat([df2.set_index('Date'),     df1.set_index('Datestart').Temp],axis=1,join='inner')
```

it create this:

```
            Temp
2010-01-01    20
2010-01-02    21
2010-01-05    19
2010-01-10    18
```

while I need this:

```
1/1/2010   20
1/2/2010   21
1/3/2010   NaN
1/4/2010   NaN
1/5/2010   19
1/6/2010   NaN
1/7/2010   NaN
1/8/2010   NaN
1/9/2010   NaN
1/15/2010   18
1/16/2010  NaN
1/17/2010  NaN
1/20/2010  NaN
1/21/2010  NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting `Datestart` to datetime first and then merging.

```
df1['Datestart'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Datestart'])
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = "outer", left_on = 'Datestart', right_on = 'Date')
```

Then you can drop the `Datestart` column and reformat your date column.

```
df3.drop('Datestart', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df3['Date'] = df3['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') 
df3.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
df3.sort_index(inplace = True)


#Prints
            Temp
Date            
01/01/2010  20.0
01/02/2010  21.0
01/03/2010   NaN
01/04/2010   NaN
01/05/2010  19.0
01/06/2010   NaN
01/07/2010   NaN
01/08/2010   NaN
01/09/2010   NaN
01/10/2010  18.0
01/11/2010   NaN
01/12/2010   NaN
01/13/2010   NaN
01/14/2010   NaN
01/15/2010   NaN
01/16/2010   NaN
01/17/2010   NaN
01/18/2010   NaN
01/19/2010   NaN
01/20/2010   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `pd.concat` call, try using `join=outer` instead of `join=inner`. This should return entries from both datasets.

Comment: Using `join=outer` returns all as NaN